# Excel vba - Dir(Path & File) not returning all matching files

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I have a strange conundrum, a DIR() command returns files as expected except for a few cases.

```
        MyFile = Dir(FilePath & FileLook)
        FileFound = ""
        FileKt = 0
        Do While MyFile <> ""
            FileFound = MyFile
            FileKt = FileKt + 1
            MyFile = Dir
        Loop
```

FilePath = the directory where the files reside
(eg: C:\Folder\ )

FileLook = the template looking for a specific file which normally has HHMM after YYYYMMDD
(eg: ERROR_FILE_20201129*)

An exception that doesn't work is a file with no extension (.txt; .zip; etc) and "." separators in the name

```
XXXXXX.XXX.PROJ.EVENT_YYYYMMDD
```

An example of a search that returned a file (the majority):
FileLook = ERROR_FILE_20201029*
returned ERROR_FILE_202010291112.txt

Note: For the exception I tried the search with and without an "*"

Comment: FilePath is the directory where the files reside (including the training "\"
FileLook is the template for the specific search - I'll modify the question to make that clear

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. But I don't understand why you would expect `XXXXXX.XXX.PROJ.EVENT_YYYYMMDD` to be matched by  `ERROR_FILE_20201129*`  Perhaps if you post the precise template you are using; and the precise full file path you feel should be being matched but is not.

Comment: Thanx Ron - the search ERROR_FILE_20201129* was an example of a successful find - the 'problem child' has no extension and "."s within the name which may be confusing file search

Comment: We are not communicating.  A successful find is the name of the file you found.  `ERROR_FILE_20201129*` is not a valid file name. (asterisks are not allowed in filenames in Windows 10) so you could not have found that file successfully.

Comment: The asterisk is valid within the DIR() command - looping through to find all files that match.  ERROR_FILE_20201129* was in FileLook, ERROR_FILE_202010291112.txt was returned in MyFile

Comment: And what file was **NOT** returned with `FileLook = ERROR_FILE_20201129*` that you think should have been?

Comment: And of course the asterisk is valid within the DIR command -- it is a wild card.

Comment: Could you share the value of `FileLook` that you used to successfully find the majority of files.

Answer (score 0):

To find just  ERROR_FILE_202011291112.txt, you can use

```
FileLook = 'ERROR_FILE_20201129*.*'
```

But any "."s ahead of the "*" seem to invalidate the filter.

Admittedly a work-around, but you can also find all the files in the directory, by letting FileLook = "" and apply a filter external to the Dir command.

```
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)
FileFound = ""
FileKt = 0
Do While MyFile <> ""
    If MyFile Like FileLook Then
        FileFound = MyFile
        FileKt = FileKt + 1
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

The following file names were in the folder I tested this against.

- ERROR_FILE_2020.11.29.1112
- ERROR_FILE_2020.11.29.1112.txt
- ERROR_FILE_202011291112.txt

All three files were evaluated using FileLook = ""

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Your solution was NOT the solution, but it did lead me to find a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you BZngr!  You did point me to a workaround.
The original

```
MyFile = Dir(FilePath & FileLook)
```

was kept.  I discovered on repeated testing that no file was found by the Dir() statement when there were just numbers at a certain point.

- PROJ.EVENT_20201030* Returned ""
- PROJ.EVENT_2020*  Returned ""
- PROJ.EVENT_202*   Returned ""
- PROJ.EVENT_20*    Returned "PROJ.EVENT_202010301421"
  As to why?  ♪Twilight Zone music♪
  There's years of files in the folder, so that's why I wanted to restrict the looping through unwanted files.  At least this way I can limit to the current century.

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped you get to a solution.